# HDMI audio doesn't show up

Tags: 16.04, sound, hdmi

I have a NUC-8265U with Intel whisky lake cpu.  I'm running 16.04.06.  The computer has 3 display options.  2 Display Ports and 1 HDMI.

If I plug in a Display Port cable to either display port, I get an option for audio over the display port in the sound preferences panel.

If I plug in the HDMI my only option is the headphone audio out.

Also, If I have only a Display Port cable plugged in.  The "Displays" configuration thinks it is a second monitor and still displays "built-in display".  If I only have HDMI plugged in, there is only one display shown.

Comment: Which kernel are you using?  If 4.4, try the latest HWE package.

Comment: It's the HWE kernel  4.15.0-99-generic

Answer (score 0):

As workaround, you tried rebooting with the hdmi connected? I had the same problem with an asus laptop and the sound only appears if you reboot the system with the HDMI connected. Only happens since 20.04